# Do we need more "fun" questions?

Tags: discussion

One of the questions asked today was on the influence of popular media on the vernacular. It was not closed at time of this question, but there was an ongoing discussion in the comment. The OP brought up the point that "favorite" questions are allowed on SO (though in CW form) and so EL&U had no "fun" questions.

Here are my questions: have we been overly harsh on certain list questions that might generate interesting answers? Should we have more CWs on the site?

Note, I'm not suggesting that every broad question is treated this way. Just the ones that could make this SE more interesting to "users of english".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's a good list question, flag it and we'll convert the question to CW. Otherwise, if it's a bad list question, close as *not constructive*.

As regarding [the specific question this came up on](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/38525/what-portions-of-the-vernacular-were-derived-directly-from-popular-media/), I've converted it to CW but not reopened the question because the community collectively closed it. In my opinion, it's a good question, and perhaps the only thing the community was worried about was the fact that it wasn't CW. If so, the community can reopen the question—if I'm an outlier, it doesn't really matter that the post is CW anyway.

Comment: well, refer to recent guidance on community wiki -- http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/

Answer (score 3):

We have plenty of fun questions. *Good* questions are fun questions. I don't adhere to the principle that "fun" trumps the FAQ or community standards. The primary reason for this is that *anyone* can claim that *any* particular question is "fun" and should get a pardon. But really, we aren't here to have "fun". We are here to answer questions about English. If that happens to be fun — great! If not — maybe this is not the right place.

The way I look at it: If someone complains about you closing one of their "fun" questions then they probably don't have any better reasons to leave it open (which is probably why it was closed.)

Answer (score 0):

About your note, it's already like this. Check the [link](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/578/should-i-flag-my-own-question-to-be-a-community-wiki) that z7sg posted in the comments of that question.